# Javascript EventSource timeout after 1,5 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I am using https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource polyfill to connect to a nodejs server through SSE. It is working fine but the connection drops everytime after 1,5 minutes and reconnect.

It seems no to come from my nodejs server because 
`curl -H Accept:text/event-stream "http://127.0.0.1:9999"`
lasts forever.

Did you guys have similar problems ?

Comment: As you are using the polyfill, and curl works fine, it will be worth saying which browser you are using. (Even better: try it in a few browsers to see if they are all affected.)

Comment: BTW, I had trouble getting the polyfill to work, so started exploring per-browser alternatives; this led to a) feeling a polyfill was the wrong solution for this particular HTML5 API; b) enough material for a book. That then led to a publisher contract. ;-)